# JS does not detect form submission

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#loginForm").on('submit', function() {
    var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    req = $.ajax({
      url: '/api/login',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    });

    req.done(function(data) {
      if (data.result == "failed") {
        let messageHandler = document.getElementById("message-handler");

        messageHandler.innerHTML = `<h3> username or password incorrect </h3>`;
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="mail" id="mail" name="mail">
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" id="loginForm">
</form>
<div id="message-handler">

</div>
```

When I click the button, it simply says Method not allowed because I am sending a post request from form. The js never detects the on submit event.

Thanks

Comment: The form element doesn't have `id="loginForm"` but you have attached a submit event handler to it. Is that a typo or is that the issue?

Comment: the button has the *id="loginForm"* not the form itself

Comment: @adiga It isn't the issue, this event can be triggered by button too. But it doesn't work tried it on the form too. And it doesn't work still couldn't find out what is wrong.

Comment: @Aalexander tried that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here in /api/login? Try to point a file like form.php or something else.

```
req = $.ajax({
      **url: '/api/login',**
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    });
```

Maybe this is the path you need to follow for your answer ;)

Comment: Yeahh it is the error I just commented everything till return statement and I just saw and added an alert() function. It works completely fine. There is an error on the endpoint. Thank you very much, why didn't I see this from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Use action='url' Or action='#' this will help to detect your request in browser.